# How to reduce the size each circle quadrant to produce gaps

Tags: swift, swift3, sprite-kit

Below is an image of my circle quadrants followed by the code. How can I reduce each arc by say, 10 points/pixels on each side so that there are gaps between the arcs? At first I was reducing them by `CGFloat(Double.pi/36)` on each side but that left didn't produce a straight gap, but a portion just sliced out, which is not what I want. I need each arc to have straight edges (horizontal and vertical) not diagonal.

[image]

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    var topRightPathNode  : SKShapeNode!
    var bottomRightPathNode  : SKShapeNode!
    var bottomLeftPathNode  : SKShapeNode!
    var topLeftPathNode  : SKShapeNode!
    override init(size: CGSize) {
        super.init(size: size)
        // TOP RIGHT
        let topRightBezierPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 0, y:0), radius: 100, startAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi/2), endAngle: 0, clockwise: false)
        topRightPathNode = SKShapeNode(path: topRightBezierPath.cgPath)
        topRightPathNode.strokeColor = SKColor.white
        topRightPathNode.lineWidth = 18
        topRightPathNode.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y:frame.midY)
        addChild(topRightPathNode)
        // BOTTOM RIGHT
        let bottomRightBezierPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 0, y:0), radius: 100, startAngle: 0 , endAngle: 3*CGFloat(Double.pi/2), clockwise: false)
        bottomRightPathNode = SKShapeNode(path: bottomRightBezierPath.cgPath)
        bottomRightPathNode.strokeColor = SKColor.orange
        bottomRightPathNode.lineWidth = 18
        bottomRightPathNode.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y:frame.midY)
        addChild(bottomRightPathNode)
        // BOTTOM LEFT
        let bottomLeftBezierPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 0, y:0), radius: 100, startAngle: 3*CGFloat(Double.pi/2), endAngle: 2*CGFloat(Double.pi/2), clockwise: false)
        bottomLeftPathNode = SKShapeNode(path: bottomLeftBezierPath.cgPath)
        bottomLeftPathNode.strokeColor = SKColor.green
        bottomLeftPathNode.lineWidth = 18
        bottomLeftPathNode.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y:frame.midY)
        addChild(bottomLeftPathNode)
        // TOP LEFT
        let topLeftBezierPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 0, y:0), radius: 100, startAngle: 2*CGFloat(Double.pi/2), endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi/2), clockwise: false)
        topLeftPathNode = SKShapeNode(path: topLeftBezierPath.cgPath)
        topLeftPathNode.strokeColor = SKColor.blue
        topLeftPathNode.lineWidth = 18
        topLeftPathNode.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y:frame.midY)
        addChild(topLeftPathNode)
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sure that this isn't what you're looking for, but if straight vertical and horizontal edges are desired, just overlay opaque rectangles that have the same color as the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is some code that when pasted into a iOS Playground generates a picture that I think matches your description.

In order to get the sides to remain parallel to the axes in the place where there are gaps, you have to do a little math to figure out what the points are.  Then you have to draw the outline of the shape you want instead of relying on the stroke width added by the drawing system.  The math is not too complicated if you're familiar with Trigonometry, but your question suggested that you might be OK.

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let radius = CGFloat(100)

let sceneSize = CGSize(width: 640, height: 480)
let sceneView = SKView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: sceneSize))

let scene = SKScene(size: sceneSize)
scene.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

let topRightPath = arcSegment(center: CGPoint.zero, radius: radius, strokeWidth: 18, gapWidth: 18)

let topRightPathNode = SKShapeNode(path: topRightPath)
topRightPathNode.fillColor = SKColor.white
topRightPathNode.lineWidth = 0
topRightPathNode.position = CGPoint(x: 320, y: 240)
scene.addChild(topRightPathNode)


var reflectOnY = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: -1.0)
let bottomRightPath = topRightPath.copy(using: &reflectOnY)!
let bottomRightPathNode = SKShapeNode(path: bottomRightPath)
bottomRightPathNode.fillColor = SKColor.orange
bottomRightPathNode.lineWidth = 0
bottomRightPathNode.position = CGPoint(x: 320, y: 240)
scene.addChild(bottomRightPathNode)


var reflectOnX = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1.0, y: 1.0)
let bottomLeftPath = bottomRightPath.copy(using: &reflectOnX)!
let bottomLeftPathNode = SKShapeNode(path: bottomLeftPath)
bottomLeftPathNode.fillColor = SKColor.green
bottomLeftPathNode.lineWidth = 0
bottomLeftPathNode.position = CGPoint(x: 320, y: 240)
scene.addChild(bottomLeftPathNode)


let topLeftPath = bottomLeftPath.copy(using: &reflectOnY)!
let topLeftPathNode = SKShapeNode(path: topLeftPath)
topLeftPathNode.fillColor = SKColor.blue
topLeftPathNode.lineWidth = 0
topLeftPathNode.position = CGPoint(x: 320, y:240)
scene.addChild(topLeftPathNode)

sceneView.presentScene(scene)

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = sceneView
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

func arcSegment(center : CGPoint,
                radius: CGFloat,
                strokeWidth: CGFloat,
                gapWidth: CGFloat) -> CGPath
{
    let halfStrokeWidth = strokeWidth / 2.0
    let outerRadius = radius + halfStrokeWidth
    let innerRadius = radius - halfStrokeWidth
    let halfGap = gapWidth / 2.0

    let outerStartAngle = CGFloat(atan2(sqrt(outerRadius * outerRadius - halfGap * halfGap), halfGap))
    let outerEndAngle = CGFloat(atan2(halfGap, sqrt(outerRadius * outerRadius - halfGap * halfGap)))

    let innerStartAngle = CGFloat(atan2(halfGap, sqrt(innerRadius * innerRadius - halfGap * halfGap)))
    let innerEndAngle = CGFloat(atan2(sqrt(innerRadius * innerRadius - halfGap * halfGap), halfGap))

    let path = CGMutablePath()

    path.addArc(center: center, radius: outerRadius, startAngle: outerStartAngle, endAngle: outerEndAngle, clockwise: true)
    // Quartz 2D will assume a "moveTo" here
    path.addArc(center: center, radius: innerRadius, startAngle: innerStartAngle, endAngle: innerEndAngle, clockwise: false)
    path.closeSubpath()


    return path
}
```

Comment: thanks, that's precisely what I need. I know this might be out of the scope of this question, but how could one arrive at circular edges instead of straight edges?

Comment: This code creates one path, but a path can be composed of multiple segments.  I would just add to the path to include segments whose center is the center point of the ends of each color stripe and whose radius is the "half stroke width"

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand your explanation. I added the following path to my existing paths `path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: center.x + radius, y: center.y), radius: halfStrokeWidth, startAngle: outerStartAngle, endAngle: outerEndAngle, clockwise: false)
` and got a strange looking rounded end

Comment: I am still trying to get the rounded ends to work. I've not made much progress since my previous comment

Comment: To find the end of one of the segments where the endcap should be drawn, you're going to do something like  `let endCapAngle = CGFloat(atan2(sqrt(radius * radius - halfGap * halfGap))`  Then to get the point on that end-cap `let endCapCenter = CGFloat(x: radius * cos(endCapAngle), y: radius * sin(endCapAngle))`.  Create a rectangle that encloses that point with a "radius" of half the stroke width and use path.addEllipse(in: rect) to put a circle into the path, centered on the end of the end cap with a radius of half the stroke width.

Comment: @ScottThompson I've been following this question, but I'm a bit lost with the creation of the `CGRect`.

Comment: @ScottThompson Getting rounded corners seems to be quite different from the original question that was asked. I can see that Hilarious404 has asked another question specifically referring to getting rounded corners. It will be more beneficial addressing it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44062346/how-to-create-a-circle-with-rounded-ends-for-each-quadrant

Comment: @NSologistic  Thanks.  I answered over on that other question. Solving the problem proved to be a lot easier than I had originally thought because you can go back to the original technique and just rely on the fact that the OS can add round joins on a wide stroke.

Comment: @ScottThompson Please could you take a look at this question for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44160439/how-to-set-physics-body-for-a-sprite-with-rounded-corners