# How to set physics body for a sprite with rounded corners

Tags: swift, swift3, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I have created a `SKShapeNode` in the following way,

```
let sprite = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(x: -20, y: -10, width: 40, height: 20), cornerRadius: 10)
```

I also set a physics body like so,

```
sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: sprite.frame.size)
```

but I realized that the collisions and contacts weren't precise, so I changed `showsPhysics` to `true` and got the following. How can I make the physics body precise, even for the rounded corners?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skphysicsbody):

Maybe the #4 is your case

[image]

```
let spaceShipTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "spaceShip.png")
```

**Spaceship 1: circular physics body**

```
let circularSpaceShip = SKSpriteNode(texture: spaceShipTexture)
circularSpaceShip.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: max(circularSpaceShip.size.width / 2,
                                                                  circularSpaceShip.size.height / 2))
```

**Spaceship 2: rectangular physics body**

```
let rectangularSpaceShip = SKSpriteNode(texture: spaceShipTexture)
rectangularSpaceShip.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: circularSpaceShip.size.width,
                                                                     height: circularSpaceShip.size.height))
```

**Spaceship 3: polygonal physics body**

```
let polygonalSpaceShip = SKSpriteNode(texture: spaceShipTexture)
let path = CGMutablePath()
path.addLines(between: [CGPoint(x: -5, y: 37), CGPoint(x: 5, y: 37), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20),
                        CGPoint(x: 56, y: -5), CGPoint(x: 37, y: -35), CGPoint(x: 15, y: -30),
                        CGPoint(x: 12, y: -37), CGPoint(x: -12, y: -37), CGPoint(x: -15, y: -30),
                        CGPoint(x: -37, y: -35), CGPoint(x: -56, y: -5), CGPoint(x: -10, y: 20),
                        CGPoint(x: -5, y: 37)])
path.closeSubpath()
polygonalSpaceShip.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(polygonFrom: path)
```

**Spaceship 4: physics body using texture’s alpha channel**

```
let texturedSpaceShip = SKSpriteNode(texture: spaceShipTexture)
texturedSpaceShip.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: spaceShipTexture,
                                              size: CGSize(width: circularSpaceShip.size.width,
                                                           height: circularSpaceShip.size.height))
```

Comment: That wouldn't work because there's no texture, it's just a SKShapeNode!

Comment: @ThiagoAM The SKShapeNode has a low performance. Transform it in a SKSpriteNode (you can create the skshapenode, thake the texture and create the skspritenode) from SKView you have: func texture(from node: SKNode) -> SKTexture?

Comment: Each method has it's strength and weaknesses,  The circle method is the fastest, the polygon method is the most precise, the texture is almost as precise, but less work, and the rectangle method is the most balanced in terms of performance and complexity.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that too much precision is very bad for performance. Read this: 
https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skphysicsbody

For general cases, it would be better to ignore the corners and stick with the normal rectangle physics, unless you REALLY need that precision. If you do, you could use a SKTexture on a SKSpriteNode instead of a ShapeNode. That would be much easier, because you could simply do this:

```
let size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 50)
let roundedRectangleTexture = SKTexture(image: UIImage(named: "textureImage")!)
let mySpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: roundedRectangleTexture, size: size)
mySpriteNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: roundedRectangleTexture, size: size)
```

With a texture, you can easily make a more detailed and precise physicsBody by simply using the `SKPhysicsBody(texture: size:)` constructor.

Comment: Note: `SKPhysicsBody(texture: size:)` does not work correctly if there is a gap in the texture.

Answer (score 0):

I would follow the documentation of [SKPhysicsBody](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skphysicsbody), and create a polygonal shape that approximates the rounded corners of your sprite.

An example on the documentation shows that you can define a polygonal physics body like so:

```
// Spaceship 3: polygonal physics body
let polygonalSpaceShip = SKSpriteNode(texture: spaceShipTexture)
let path = CGMutablePath()
path.addLines(between: [CGPoint(x: -5, y: 37), CGPoint(x: 5, y: 37), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20),
                        CGPoint(x: 56, y: -5), CGPoint(x: 37, y: -35), CGPoint(x: 15, y: -30),
                        CGPoint(x: 12, y: -37), CGPoint(x: -12, y: -37), CGPoint(x: -15, y: -30),
                        CGPoint(x: -37, y: -35), CGPoint(x: -56, y: -5), CGPoint(x: -10, y: 20),
                        CGPoint(x: -5, y: 37)])
path.closeSubpath()
polygonalSpaceShip.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(polygonFrom: path)
```